# How to create a init.d script for openssh-server which was compiled and installed from source using configure + make + make install?

Tags: 12.04, apt, services, init.d, openssh

I have installed openssh-server in my Ubuntu PC using `apt-get install openssh-server`. The version is 5.9.

Now, I would like to compile and install openssh-server version 6.2 from source codes. I have successfully downloaded the source codes, and run the following commands:

`./configure`
`make`
`make install`

I found that the new version of openssh-server was installed into /usr/local/sbin/. The old version of openssh-server was in /usr/sbin/.

I found that the service script in /etc/init.d/ssh is still pointing to /usr/sbin/. And the old openssh-server (v5.9) is still running.

1. How can I **replace** the old openssh-server with the new openssh-server that I have just compiled and installed?
2. How can I create a init.d script to start and stop the new openssh-server that I've compiled from source?
3. How to start the new openssh-server on boot?
4. When I install openssh-server using `apt-get install`, the config files will be installed into /etc/ssh/. If I compile and install it from source, where is the config file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you edit the init script (looks like there are 2 lines below each other that point to /usr/sbin/)? That would solve 1 and also solve question 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just installed version 6.4p from source and the config files are placed in

```
> /usr/local/etc$ ll total 284
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 242153 Jan 10 21:20 moduli
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1576 Jan 10 21:20 ssh_config
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2583 Jan 13 09:46 sshd_config
> -rw------- 1 root root    672 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_dsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    610 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root    227 Jan 10 21:20 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182 Jan 10 21:20 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root    985 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    650 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root   1679 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_rsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    402 Jan 13 09:28 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

To get the old version removed, I've set up the new one to run on a different port, copied the init script of the old version and modified it to point to the new installed one.  I can now have the two versions running so I can test the new install, I'm keeping the old one around for a day or so in case something goes pear shaped so I've still got access (my server is totally remote).
Once I'm happy, I can just remove the old version using apt, clean up any config files I may still have lying around and then reboot.
Good luck!